# Check if the device can hover

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have read a lot of articles about how to check if the device can hover for making a good responsive design, but still no solution. I tried with media(hover:not) but it works only on Google Chrome on mobile. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: although you can implement such a check it is considered a bad practice because the device can have both types of input (mouse and touch) simultaneously

Comment: I have a hamburger menu and ordinary dropdown menu with elements that appear on hover

Comment: I tried to make the website only with media queries for width, but my tablet is big and I cannot use the website with it

Comment: Show the CSS and HTML as a [mcve]

Comment: You can see the website on http://babanovi.bg

Comment: Look at the hamburger menu on the left and the ordinary menu in the center. I want hamburger menu to be shown only on touch devices and ordinary menu to be shown only on desktop devices.

Comment: Can you help me @zer00ne?

Comment: @СимеонСимеонов Ok review and test my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following demo utilizes [**MediaQueryList API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) to control the Drawer plugin at the breakpoint of 1025px (just a guess since you didn't provide any info in regards to your iPad). Details of what to remove, add, and change are commented in demo.

Basically after page loads, if the screen is > 1025px then the Drawer plugin is removed and the side menu is hidden. If it's < 1025px, then plugin is loaded and side-menu is visible. This will occur should there ever be a resizing of the screen as well.

For the touch issue I have added [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/). You have jQuery UI loaded (although I haven't noticed it being used on your site). jQuery UI does not recognize touch events so this plugin will translate touch events into equivalent versions of the mouse events so that jQuery UI will react to touch events. Not really sure it matters if you only have mouse events registered on desktop and touch events only on mobile. If you decide that you aren't going to use jQuery UI, then use this polyfill [Pointer Events jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/PEP) which allows you to use touch, mouse, etc. pointer type events.

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="bg">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--|SWAP| positions of <link>s~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|BEGIN|-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/drawer/3.2.2/css/drawer.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|END|-->
<!--|ADD| media query here or in style.css|BEGIN|~~~-->
<style>
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .drawer-toggle.drawer-hamburger { display: none !important }
}
</style>
<!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|END|-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-touch-punch@0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iScroll/5.2.0/iscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/drawer/3.2.2/js/drawer.min.js"></script>
<!--|REMOVE| this <script> tag~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|BEGIN|->
<script>$(document).ready(() => $('.drawer').drawer())</script>
<!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|END|-->
<title>Счетоводна къща Елина</title>
</head>

<body class="drawer drawer--left">
<div id="wrapper" role="main"> 
   <!--|ADD| an #id to this <div>~~~~~~~~~~~~|BEGIN|-->
   <div id='mobNav' role="banner"> 
      <!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|END|-->
      <button type="button" class="drawer-toggle drawer-hamburger"> <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="drawer-hamburger-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <nav class="drawer-nav" role="navigation">
         <ul class="drawer-menu">
            <li><a class="drawer-brand" href="#">Начало</a></li>
            <li><a class="drawer-brand" href="./services.html">Услуги</a></li>
            <li><a class="drawer-menu-item" href="./accounting-services.html">Счетоводни услуги</a></li>
            <li><a class="drawer-menu-item" href="./taxing-services.html">Данъчни услуги</a></li>
            <li><a class="drawer-menu-item" href="./administration-of-remuneration.html">Администриране на възнаграждения</a></li>
            <li><a class="drawer-menu-item" href="./others.html">Други</a></li>
            <li><a class="drawer-brand" href="./prices.html">Цени</a></li>
            <li><a class="drawer-brand" href="./about-us.html">За нас</a></li>
            <li><a class="drawer-brand" href="./contacts.php">Контакти</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>
   
   <!-- header -->
   <header>
      <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Лого">
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Начало</a></li>
            <li><a href="./services.html">Услуги</a>
               <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><a href="./accounting-services.html">Счетоводни услуги</a></li>
                  <li><a href="./taxing-services.html">Данъчни услуги</a></li>
                  <li><a href="./administration-of-remuneration.html">Администриране на възнаграждения</a></li>
                  <li><a href="./others.html">Други</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="./prices.html">Цени</a></li>
            <li><a href="./about-us.html">За нас</a></li>
            <li><a href="./contacts.php">Контакти</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <hr>
   </header>
   
   <!-- slider -->
   <div id="slider">
      <img id="left-arrow" src="./images/arrow.png" alt="left-arrow" class="controllers">
      <img id="right-arrow" src="./images/arrow.png" alt="right-arrow" class="controllers">
      <div id="circle-controllers-section">
         <div id="0" class="circle-controllers"></div>
         <div id="1" class="circle-controllers"></div>
         <div id="2" class="circle-controllers"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script src="./scripts/get-content.js"></script> 
   <script src="./scripts/slider.js"></script> 
   
   <!-- email form -->
   <form id="email-form" method="GET">
      <div id="email-container">
         <h2>Пишете ни</h2>
         <label for="myEmail">Имейл:</label>
         <input id="myEmail" type="email" name="myEmail" placeholder="Въведете имейл" required>
         <label for="myName">Имена:</label>
         <input id="myName" type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Въведете име и фамилия" required>
         <label for="subject">Предмет:</label>
         <select name="subject" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Изберете предмет</option>
            <option value="Счетоводни услуги">Счетоводни услуги</option>
            <option value="Данъчни услуги">Данъчни услуги</option>
            <option value="Администриране на възнаграждения">Администриране на възнаграждения</option>
            <option value="Друго">Друго</option>
         </select>
         <label for="message">Съобщение:</label>
         <textarea id="message" rows="4" cols="40" name="message" placeholder="Въведете съобщение" required></textarea>
         <div id="mistake-field"> </div>
         <input type="submit" name="button" value="Изпрати"/>
      </div>
   </form>
   
   <!-- footer -->
   <footer>
      <hr>
      <div id="footer">
         <div>
            <img id="logo" src="./images/logo.png" alt="Лого">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%95%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%94-368462670244655/?modal=admin_todo_tour">
            <img id="facebook" src="./images/facebook-logo.png" alt="Фейсбук">
            Посетете и харесайте нашата страница във Фейсбук.</a> </div>
         <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>
   </footer>
</div>
<!--|ADD| <script> here or on external file |BEGIN|-->
<script>
    
/* Create a mediaQueryList (mql) with the breakpoint  
|| matching your iPad width when in landscape mode
*/   
var mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1025px)');

// The callback function passing the Event Object
function modDrawer(e) {
 
 // if change media event matches the mql...
  if (e.matches) {
  // ...close .drawer...
  $('.drawer').drawer('close');
  //...remove the plugin...
        $('.drawer').drawer('destroy');
  //...and hide the menu.
  document.querySelector('#mobNav').style.display = 'none';
  // Otherwise...
  } else {
  //...start the plugin...
        $('.drawer').drawer();
  //...make the menu...
  document.querySelector('#mobNav').style.display = 'block';
  //...and the button visisble.
  document.querySelector('.drawer-toggle.drawer-hamburger').style.cssText = 'block !important';

  }
}
/* Register the mql to listen for a media change
|| modDrawer() is the callback
*/
mql.addListener(modDrawer);
</script>
<!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|END|-->

</body>
</html>
```